# How to express a "some of which are" and "not all are" relationship with enhanced entity-relationship diagrams?

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams

For example:

`Gardens` have attribute `gate`, `Condos` have attribute `door`. Some of the `Gardens` and `Condos` *are* `Private_Properties`. On the other hand, `Private_Properties` are not restricted to only `Gardens` or `Condos`.

How can these non-exclusive relationship be illustrated with an enhanced entity-relationship diagram (EERD)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent a 1..* relationship

Notation is quite standard but it may vary a little depending on your EER tool... Since I work with Oracle, I'm used to Oracle Data Modeler notation...

Check the picture... and good luck!

[image: Oracle Data Modeler diagram]